# postgres get left table all data then group by count right table matching data

Tags: postgresql

I have two table `products`  and `summary_orders`.

products table has two fields

```
id | name
1  | apple
2  | orange
```

summary_orders table has fields

```
id | product_id | user_id | get_count 
1  | 1          | 1       | 5
2  | 1          | 1       | 4
```

My desire output for user_id 1 is

```
name   total 
Apple  9
orange 0
```

I have tried below query

```
SELECT products.name,
       SUM(summary_orders.get_count) AS total
FROM 
    summary_orders
LEFT JOIN 
    products ON products.id = summary_orders.product_id
WHERE 
    user_id = 1
GROUP BY product_id,products.id
ORDER BY product_id ASC
```

I am getting result

```
name   total 
Apple  9
```

Orange is missing. How can I get the count also with orange ?

Answer (score 0):

you should change the direction of your join query, there are two ways:

1. change `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`
2. first query on table **products** then `INNER/LEFT` `JOIN` with  **summary_orders**

you can read more about join and direction join [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Edit Section:

also your query grammer is wrong, you select a column that not in group by result:

```
SELECT products.name,
       SUM(summary_orders.get_count) AS total
FROM 
    summary_orders
RIGHT JOIN 
    products ON products.id = summary_orders.product_id
WHERE 
    user_id = 1
GROUP BY products.id,products.name
ORDER BY products.id ASC
```

Comment: I have tried in postgres query editor and not getting all product name. But It may work in mysql.

Comment: this is methodology of relational database not depend to DBMS type, it works actually, get link of your test case @RezaulZablu

Comment: @RezaulZablu your query have bad grammer , i edit my soulotion to be fixed your second problem.